# Get Height of a div Which is Absolute-Positioned and Hidden

Tags: jquery, html, height, hidden, absolute

I have been reading and trying to solve this problem, but I can't find a solution.

I'm trying to get the height of a div, to update another div's height and make cool jQuery animations. It's all triggered by an ajax request (which works ok).

[Here is a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/97Xx5/2/)

I don't know how to get the height of the `#bigBox`, because it always return 0.

**edited**

All the soloutions worked, but they didn't do what I expected.
I need to calculate the height after the `#bigBox` fade out.

Finally I managed to do it.

I change the class `.toToggle` to the div `#bigBox`, instead of beeing in it's parent div. This was done to avoid the parent beeing `display: none;`. Now the same element is hidden, so it works

[Here is the final solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Zqe6z/)

Thank you all! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hiding it before taking the height, so when you take the height it will be '0'.

try this instead:

```
var height = $("#bigBox").height();
$(".toToggle").fadeOut(600, "swing",function(){

    alert(height);

    $(".toToggle").fadeIn(500);
});
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/97Xx5/3/).

Comment: I get the height after the animation begins, because when the div fade out, the content of the div changes... That's why I need to get the height, tnx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Hidden elements have no height, by definition. You'll need to, for example, position it absolutely and offscreen (see below), show it, get its height, and hide it again.

.offscreen {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}

Update: After looking more closely at your demo, why not just get the height before your animation begins?

http://jsfiddle.net/97Xx5/5/

```
var height = $("#bigBox").height();

$(".toToggle").fadeOut(600, "swing", function () {
    alert(height);

    $(".toToggle").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: I get the height after the animation begins, because when the div fade out, the content of the div changes... That's why I need to get the height :D

Comment: Then you'll need to re-work your function to have explicit steps, one of which must leave the element visible and offscreen like I described.